# Dynamically updating hosts file with new hostname for EC2 VPC instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, hosts, amazon-vpc

I am getting the following error when running a `sudo` command on Ubuntu 14 server on EC2/VPC on Amazon Web Services.

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-xxx-xx-x-xx
```

I replaces the private IP address of the server with x's.

In order to solve this, I need to edit `/etc/hosts` file. When I add the following line to the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 ip-xxx-xx-x-xx
```

Now I don't get the error. The value after the 127.0.0.1 resolves to the `hostname` command value.
The problem is that I might create an AMI and restore the server in the future, so the private IP will change. In [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=545056), they recommended to add a script that automatically update the hosts file with the new IP (the `hostname` value) so it will work when restoring a server from AMI or when autoscaling.

How can I update the hosts file with the hostname value, so I won't need to worry about any future issues?

Comment: There should be no need to update the hosts file, if you configure your VPC to resolve the names, [as discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27747125/1695906).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloud Platforms- sudo: unable to resolve host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741098/cloud-platforms-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you, for some reason, cannot enable `DNS hostnames` on your VPC, then you should do exactly what was suggested in the AWS forum. Write a script to automatically change the `/etc/hosts` file. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOCAL_HOSTNAME=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname)
cat << EOF >> /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 $LOCAL_HOSTNAME
EOF
```

**NOTE**: This will overwrite the entire hosts file, so make sure you write all you need in there.

According to the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html), `local-hostname` will return something like `ip-10-251-50-12.ec2.internal`. If that's not exactly what you want, check the other available metadata in the documentation beforementioned.

Suppose you don't want the `.ec2.internal` part, you can customize the script to get rid of that part using `cut`. Example:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname | cut -d '.' -f1
```

### Run on startup

There are a few alternatives to make it run on startup. I recommend you to call it from `rc.local` (see [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093706/is-it-correct-to-use-the-rc-local-file-to-start-a-program-when-the-system-starts)). Don't forget to give your script the execute permission.

Comment: a few noob questions: What is the ip in the curl, where I write the script and what extension file is it?

Comment: 1) That IP is used by AWS (and possible other cloud providers) to distribute metadata to their instances. Refer to the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) for more informations; 2) You should write the script in the root home directory (/root generally). I'd name it something like `rewrite-etc-hosts.sh`, then give it execute permission: `chmod u+x /root/rewrite-etc-hosts.sh`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll follow your guidance.

Comment: UPDATE: Typo error, I am checking again, should work now.